# Get a clean string from an informal string representation

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble splitting a string into lines. 
I receive a string that seems to be defined as

```
txt = str(b"line1 \n line2")
```

Which, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) is transformed into the informal representation of the string.

It's like I am receiving a script defined as

```
txt = "b'line1 \n line2'"
```

How can I transform my data into

```
txt = "line1 \n line2"
```

Without doing something as ugly as

```
txt = txt[2:-1]
```

EDIT: Saw marked as duplicate but the other question does not seem to apply:

```
txt = str(b"line1\nline2")                                                                     
txt.decode('ascii')                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-0ccdab40ee23> in <module>
----> 1 txt.decode('ascii')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: `b"line1 \n line2".decode()`

Comment: @L3viathan: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: I didn't say decode the string, I said decode the bytestring.